# Change default audio output device with NAudio

Tags: c#, .net, naudio

I want to change windows 10 default audio output with NAudio.

NAudio has an api to get the default audio endpoint:

```cs
var enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
var audioOutputDevice = enumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(DataFlow.Render, Role.Console);
```

I want to set that default audio endpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I couldn't find any solution with NAudio. I do it with PowerShell:

1. Add **AudioDeviceCmdlets** nuget package to your project from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AudioDeviceCmdlets).
2. Then we should use `Set-AudioDevice` command to set default audio device. It uses either device id or index. In the C# code we need a **PowerShell** nuget package. The package has been added as a dependency of **AudioDeviceCmdlets** nuget package, so take no action and go to the next step.
3. Use this code to set default device:

```cs
InitialSessionState iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
iss.ImportPSModule(new string[]
{
Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "AudioDeviceCmdlets.dll")
});

Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(iss);
runspace.Open();

Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();

Command command_set = new Command("Set-AudioDevice");
CommandParameter param_set = new CommandParameter("ID", id);
command_set.Parameters.Add(param_set);
pipeline.Commands.Add(command_set);

// Execute PowerShell script
var results = pipeline.Invoke();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this tutorial, Mahdi!
Any idea how to cast results to AudioDevice?

Comment: I found it  
results.Select(r=>r.BaseObject).Cast<AudioDevice>().ToList();

Answer (score 4):

I'm adding this as a simpler way of changing the audio device. I've looked at the source lib [AudioDeviceCmdlets](https://github.com/frgnca/AudioDeviceCmdlets) you mentioned and I've found another way of doing this.

Looking at the class [AudioDeviceCmdlets](https://github.com/frgnca/AudioDeviceCmdlets/blob/master/SOURCE/AudioDeviceCmdlets.cs) you can find this piece of code at line [429](https://github.com/frgnca/AudioDeviceCmdlets/blob/master/SOURCE/AudioDeviceCmdlets.cs#L429) where DeviceCollection[i].ID is the ID of the new device:

```
 // Create a new audio PolicyConfigClient
 PolicyConfigClient client = new PolicyConfigClient();
 // Using PolicyConfigClient, set the given device as the default playback communication device
 client.SetDefaultEndpoint(DeviceCollection[i].ID, ERole.eCommunications);
 // Using PolicyConfigClient, set the given device as the default playback device
 client.SetDefaultEndpoint(DeviceCollection[i].ID, ERole.eMultimedia);
```

Well, it's as simple as importing this library an making the same call:

```
 public void SetDefaultMic(string id)
 {
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id)) return;
     CoreAudioApi.PolicyConfigClient client = new CoreAudioApi.PolicyConfigClient();
     client.SetDefaultEndpoint(id, CoreAudioApi.ERole.eCommunications);
     client.SetDefaultEndpoint(id, CoreAudioApi.ERole.eMultimedia);
 }
```

Also, by doing it this way you will not get a cast exception when combined with NAudio on a thread separated (Added this note as it happened to me).

Comment: Any idea if that works with Win11? I cannot test it myself